# Returning data from many rows with different values

Tags: python, sql

so i have been having a problem with my code.

What im trying to do is i have a list set up like:

```
locationList = [['mt', 'moon', 'mt-moon'], ['misty', 'mis'], ['surge', 'sur'], ect...]
```

And what this is is they are inputs the people use, so instead of having to input the whole word, they just do an abbreviation.

Now i have these stored in a DB, with The persons name, their points, the bet loctaion, and betted points. Like this:

```
**Name** | **Points** | **BetLocation** | **BetPoints**
-------- | ---------- | --------------- | -------------
James    | 1000       | mis             | 100          
Mike     | 3000       | misty           | 700          
Dave     | 400        | mt              | 200
```

Now what im trying to do is when i choose a winning location, like say i choose misty, it will return both James and Mike but not Dave.

```
if any(winner in s for s in locationList):
        c = conn.cursor()
        search = winner
        for sublist in locationList:
            if sublist[0] == search:
                print(sublist)
                print(str(sublist)[1:-1])
                test1 = '(' + str(sublist)[1:-1] + ')'
                print(test1)
                c.execute("SELECT Name, CurrentBetValue FROM Users WHERE CurrentBetLocation IN('misty', 'mis')")
                data = c.fetchall()
                print(data)
                for f in data:
                    kek = (f[1], f[0])
                    c.execute('UPDATE Users SET Points = Points + (? * 2) WHERE Name = ?', kek)
                conn.commit()
                betReset()
                betsOpen = False
                return send_message('"'+str(winner) + '"' + ' is the winning location, points have been updated.')
```

Each print returns:

- ['misty', 'mis']
- 'misty', 'mis'
- ('misty', 'mis')

Now this works due to me having manually put in `IN('misty', 'mis')`
And returns what i want it to.

However if i change it to `c.execute("SELECT Name, CurrentBetValue FROM Users WHERE CurrentBetLocation IN ?", test1)`

> c.execute("SELECT Name, CurrentBetValue FROM Users WHERE CurrentBetLocation IN ?", test1)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

I was wondering if anybody could help!

Comment: I don't see any php code.

Comment: Yeah sorry idk why i put that in oops

Comment: Knowing the db and the interface you use would help.

Comment: Its just a Local .db file

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a guess from "Its just a Local .db file" that you're using SQLite and the built-in `sqlite3` Python module.

If so, I think you want this:

```
c.execute("SELECT Name, CurrentBetValue FROM Users WHERE CurrentBetLocation IN ({})".format(",".join("?"*len(sublist))), sublist)
```

`"?" * len(sublist)` gives you a sequence of *n* question marks for *n* elements in the sublist. Joining that with commas, you get a nice parameterized command: `"... IN (?,?)"`. Finally, you can pass in your `sublist` as those parameters.

Here's a complete working example with a couple comments inline so you can see what's happening:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("create table test (name text, location text)")
c.execute("insert into test values (?, ?)", ("James", "mis"))
c.execute("insert into test values (?, ?)", ("Mike", "misty"))
c.execute("insert into test values (?, ?)", ("Dave", "mt"))

sublist = ["misty", "mis"]

# select name from test where location in (?,?)
command = "select name from test where location in ({})".format(",".join("?" * len(sublist)))

# select name from test where location in ('misty', 'mis')
c.execute(command, sublist)

print(c.fetchall()) # [('James',), ('Mike',)]
```

If my assumptions were wrong, and you're using a database other than SQLite or a module other than `sqlite3`, please tell us what you're using. (For future questions: this is quite important information to include. Even better would be to provide a complete runnable example.)

Comment: yeah i am using sqlite3, i also mannged to get it working by doing `c.execute("SELECT Name, CurrentBetValue FROM Users WHERE CurrentBetLocation IN {0}".format(test1))`

Comment: @Jonese1234 Doing that defeats the security benefits of using parameterized queries, so I'd advise against it.